# Multiple IF Statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a question about `IF` statements.

I wanted to use VBA, but the other guy I am working with doesn't know how to do it, so I am trying to only use worksheet formulas. So, I figured the best way to make Excel do what I want is with `IF` statements.

So I have two columns that calculate an ideal value for 32 rows. Some have one answers and some have two. The next thing I want to do is calculate if the riser needs to be pulled. It will need to be pulled if the calculated `DC` values from row 2 do not equal the calculated values for row 1. I wrote the following equation in the `Riser Pull` column.

```
=IF(E3=E2;"No";IF(F3=E2;"No";IF(E3=F2;"No";IF(F3=F2;"No";"Yes"))))
```

But for some reason it is not working properly. Any suggestions?

```
DC  DC2 Riser Pull
B2  -       No
B2  -       No
B7  C7      Yes
B2  -       Yes
C7  B7      Yes
C2  -       Yes
B7  -       No
C7  B7      No
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Could you explain what you mean by the formula "not working properly"? Which `Riser Pull` values in the sample table do not match what you want to be returned?

Comment: Also, does your table include hyphens in the `DC2` column, or does that just signify a blank cell?

Comment: Thanks! The error was occuring towards the bottom of the my table (row 29 I think). Manged to fix that by adding another column that chose a DC from either of the first two columns that picked the same DC if possible. The hyphens are there to signifiy a blank cell.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to figure out whether the data you provided showed an error. I can't figure out how what you show here differs from what you want. If you could, please indicate which rows in your sample data have an incorrect `Riser Pull` value.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned elsewhere, you should be using commas, not semicolons.

In addition, because you only have two possible return values, I would recommend using the [`OR` function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/or.php) instead of nesting your `IF` statements:

```
=IF(OR(E3=E2, F3=E2, E3=F2, F3=F2), "No", "Yes")
```

Comment: Llama, no you don't, it depends on your language settings. I'm from Belgium and I use `;` instead of `,`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use commas instead of semicolons in your formula:

```
=IF(E3=E2,"No",IF(F3=E2,"No",IF(E3=F2,"No",IF(F3=F2,"No","Yes"))))
```

If you are going to have a lot of these yukky nested if clauses, it might still be worth considering a little bit of VBA to introduce a SWITCH function - see this [example](http://datapigtechnologies.com/blog/index.php/using-the-switch-function-in-excel/), which can then be used as a formula and is much easier to follow.

Comment: Ill have to look into that. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @Gogoud, no you don't, it depends on your language settings. I'm from Belgium and I use `;` instead of `,`

Comment: @CustomX oh I never knew that, how weird